# Android onPreviewFrame callback not getting called for the camera

Tags: java, android, callback, android-camera

I'm trying to get the data from onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera). But it doesn't seem to be working. Do you see any problems with this code? Most of this just came straight from http://developer.android.com/training/camera/cameradirect.html

```
public class UAVCamera extends Thread {

    Camera mCamera;
    CameraPreview mPreview;

    public UAVCamera(Context context) {
        mPreview = new CameraPreview(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        safeCameraOpen();
        mPreview.setCamera(mCamera);
    }

    private boolean safeCameraOpen() {
        boolean qOpened = false;

        try {
            releaseCameraAndPreview();
            mCamera = Camera.open();
            qOpened = (mCamera != null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Log.e(getString(R.string.app_name), "failed to open Camera");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return qOpened;    
    }

    private void releaseCameraAndPreview() {
        mPreview.setCamera(null);
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my preview class

```
class CameraPreview extends ViewGroup implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
    SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    Camera mCamera;

    CameraPreview(Context context) {
        super(context);

        mSurfaceView = new SurfaceView(context);
        addView(mSurfaceView);

        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        mHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    private void stopPreviewAndFreeCamera() {

        if (mCamera != null) {
            /*
              Call stopPreview() to stop updating the preview surface.
            */
            mCamera.stopPreview();

            /*
              Important: Call release() to release the camera for use by other applications. 
              Applications should release the camera immediately in onPause() (and re-open() it in
              onResume()).
            */
            mCamera.release();

            mCamera = null;
        }
    }

    public void setCamera(Camera camera) {
        if (mCamera == camera) { return; }

        stopPreviewAndFreeCamera();

        mCamera = camera;

        if (mCamera != null) {

            try {
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            /*
              Important: Call startPreview() to start updating the preview surface. Preview must 
              be started before you can take a picture.
              */
            mCamera.startPreview();            
            mCamera.setPreviewCallback(new PreviewCallback() {

                  public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

                  }
                });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3, int arg4) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Here is my activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private UAVCamera uavCamera;    

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        uavCamera = new UAVCamera(this);
        uavCamera.start();
    }                           
}
```

I really don't even need to show the picture to the user. I just need to get to the data. Is it possible to do that? I put a break point on onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) but it never gets hit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the instructions on http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#custom-camera
The problem was that I was not creating an activity. I would like to run this as a service and be able to get this information even with the screen is not on. Not sure how to do that.

Comment: Its not possible presumably for security reasons among others. you can't even capture in a foregrounded activity unless the image is actually shown on a surface even.

Comment: @rickster I'm having the same problem like you, the onpreviewframe not called, have got any solutions?  [My problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29310279/4388898)

Answer (score 0):

You should use
`setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer (Camera.PreviewCallback cb)` instead of `setPreviewCallback`.
And, add the callback buffer using `addCallbackBuffer(byte[])`

When you use `addCallbackBuffer(byte[])`, byte length is more than preview size (width*height).
Then, I think you can get the data in `onPreviewFrame` method.