# mCamera.setpreview{@override onPreviewFrame() } not work

Tags: java, android

- I want to *record videos and analysis the current bitmap* in service.
- So I register `surfaceHolder.addCallback` in `onStartCommand` function.
- And set `mCamera.setPreviewCallback` in `surfaceCreated` function.
- When I start the Service, it seems that the `onPreviewFrame` function never work.

I don't know why, Can anybody give me a hand?

Here is my code of `onStartCommand` function in Service.

```
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if (Util.checkCameraHardware(this)) {
        mCamera = Util.getCameraInstance();
        if (mCamera != null) {
            SurfaceView sv = new SurfaceView(this);

            WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
            WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(1, 1,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
                    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);


            SurfaceHolder sh = sv.getHolder();

            sv.setZOrderOnTop(true);
            sh.setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);


            sh.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                    Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
                    mCamera.setParameters(params);
                    Camera.Parameters p = mCamera.getParameters();

                    List<Camera.Size> listSize;

                    listSize = p.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
                    Camera.Size mPreviewSize = listSize.get(2);
                    Log.v("TAG", "preview width = " + mPreviewSize.width
                            + " preview height = " + mPreviewSize.height);
                    p.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);

                    listSize = p.getSupportedPictureSizes();
                    Camera.Size mPictureSize = listSize.get(2);
                    Log.v("TAG", "capture width = " + mPictureSize.width
                            + " capture height = " + mPictureSize.height);
                    p.setPictureSize(mPictureSize.width, mPictureSize.height);
                    mCamera.setParameters(p);
                    try {
                        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);

    /***************************************************************************/
                        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(new Camera.PreviewCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                                if (_calibrationsLeft == -1)
                                    return;

                                if (_calibrationsLeft > 0) {
                                    // Doing calibration !

                                    if (_currentFaceDetectionThread != null
                                            && _currentFaceDetectionThread.isAlive()) {
                                        // Drop Frame
                                        return;
                                    }

                                    // No face detection started or already finished
                                    _processTimeForLastFrame = System.currentTimeMillis()
                                            - _lastFrameStart;
                                    _lastFrameStart = System.currentTimeMillis();

                                    if (_currentFaceDetectionThread != null) {
                                        _calibrationsLeft--;
                                        updateMeasurement(_currentFaceDetectionThread.getCurrentFace());

                                        if (_calibrationsLeft == 0) {
                                            doneCalibrating();
                                            return;
                                        }
                                    }

                                    _currentFaceDetectionThread = new FaceDetectionThread(data,
                                            _previewSize);
                                    _currentFaceDetectionThread.start();

                                } else {
                                    // Simple Measurement

                                    if (_currentFaceDetectionThread != null
                                            && _currentFaceDetectionThread.isAlive()) {
                                        // Drop Frame
                                        return;
                                    }

                                    // No face detection started or already finished
                                    _processTimeForLastFrame = System.currentTimeMillis()
                                            - _lastFrameStart;
                                    _lastFrameStart = System.currentTimeMillis();

                                    if (_currentFaceDetectionThread != null)
                                        updateMeasurement(_currentFaceDetectionThread.getCurrentFace());

                                    _currentFaceDetectionThread = new FaceDetectionThread(data,
                                            _previewSize);
                                    _currentFaceDetectionThread.start();
                                }
                            }
                        });
     /****************************************************************************/
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    mCamera.startPreview();
                    MessageHUB.get().sendMessage(MessageHUB.LOG_PREVIEW, null);
                    mCamera.unlock();
                    calibrate();
                }

                @Override
                public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
                }

                @Override
                public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                }
            });


            wm.addView(sv, params);

        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", "==== get Camera from service failed");

        }
    } else {
        Log.d("TAG", "==== There is no camera hardware on device.");
    }

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

Comment: Best way to find out what is wrong is to have `System.out.println("phase 1");` whenever there is a ruturn statement to determine if it is being cancelled.

Comment: And the surfaceCreated method is called? How do you start the service? When I try run an example with your code, it crashes in the line: wm.addView(sv, params);

Comment: Is the service registerd in the manifest?

Comment: https://github.com/ZhuFengdaaa/backgroundRecorder My code is here. Thank you for your attention ~

Comment: @RobinDijkhof Yes I do.

Comment: Try calling startPreview() before you set the preview callback but after you call setPreviewDisplay(holder).

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're stopping camera preview inside surfacechanged

```
mCamera.stopPreview();
```

Try restarting preview inside onSurfaceChanged

[Quoting the docs](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/cameradirect.html#camera-preview)

> The preview must also be restarted in the preview class
>   surfaceChanged() callback method.